# Jest with async function calls before and after setTimeout

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, testing, jestjs

I have a main function which calls two async functions with sleep function in between. This is a basic example:

**index.js**

```
const func1 = async() => {
    setTimeout(()=>{console.log('func 1...')}, 1000);
}

const func2 = async() => {
    setTimeout(()=>{console.log('func 2...')}, 1000);
}

const sleep = ms => {
    console.log(`Sleeping for ${ms/1000} seconds`);
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        setTimeout(resolve, ms);
    })
}

const main = async() => {
    try {
    await func1();
    // Sleeping for a long long time
    console.log('Before Sleep');
    await sleep(2000000);
    console.log('After Sleep')
    await func2();
    return 'success';
    } catch(err) {
        console.log(err);
        return 'error'
    }
}
```

And this is my test code:

**index.test.js**

```
const index = require('./index');

jest.useFakeTimers();

describe('Testing index.js...', () => {
    test('Should return success', async() => {
        const promise = index();
        jest.advanceTimersByTime(2000000);
        promise.then(response => {
            expect(response).toBe('success');
        }) 
    });
})
```

The test passes, but the console shows the following:

```
func 1...
Before Sleep
Sleeping for 2000 seconds
```

I tried the same this, but with func1() and func2() being synchronous functions:

```
const func1 = () => {
    console.log('func 1...');
}

const func2 = () => {
    console.log('func 2...');

}

const sleep = ms => {
    // Sleeping for a long time
    console.log(`Sleeping for ${ms/1000} seconds`);
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        setTimeout(resolve, ms);
    })
}

const main = async() => {
    try {
    func1();
    // Sleeping for a long long time
    console.log('Before Sleep');
    await sleep(2000000);
    console.log('After Sleep')
    func2();
    return 'success';
    } catch(err) {
        console.log(err);
        return 'error'
    }
}
```

In that case, the test passes and the logs are also as expected:

```
func 1...
Before Sleep
Sleeping for 2000 seconds
After Sleep
func 2...
```

In the same synchronous code, if I make func1 async (keeping func2 synchronous), the problem reappears.
If func1 is synchronous and func2 is async, everything works as expected.

I have also tried using jest.runAllTimers() and jest.runOnlyPendingTimers(). I have also tried using async-await in the test file, but that (understandably) gives a timeout error:

**index.test.js** using async-await

```
const index = require('./index');

jest.useFakeTimers();

describe('Testing index.js...', () => {
    test('Should return success', async() => {
        const promise = index();
        jest.advanceTimersByTime(3000000);
        const response = await promise;
        expect(response).toBe('success');  
    });
})
```

**Console**:

```
func 1...
Before Sleep
Sleeping for 2000 seconds
```

**Error**:

```
Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within the 5000ms timeout specified by jest.setTimeout.Timeout
```

How can I make this work?
I have gone through and tried a solutions on lot of Github issues in jest, and also a lot of questions on stack overflow, none of the solutions seem to work.

I am using jest 25.5.4

Edit: I also tried increasing the value in jest.advanceTimersBytTime() to a day. And also tried making the function in describe async.

Comment: I think the describe function also needs to be async.

Comment: Why so? And anyways I tried making the describe function async. Same result.

Comment: And this would be a mistake because describe shouldn't be async.

Answer (score 2):

I've had a similar issue recently, what worked for me is to advance the timers from within an async-call. Seems like jest does not support setting the timers within a promise (see https://github.com/facebook/jest/pull/5171#issuecomment-528752754). Try doing:

```
describe('Testing index.js...', () => {
  it('Should return success', () => {    
    const promise = main();
    Promise.resolve().then(() => jest.advanceTimersByTime(2000005));
    return promise.then((res) => {
      expect(res).toBe('success');
    });

  });
});
```

Comment: This does solve the issue when func2 is synchronous.  But when func2 is async, the console.log('After Sleep) gets executed, but the console.log() statement in func2() doesn't get called.

Comment: You're right, I missed that - I'll take another look :)

Comment: `async` shouldn't be mixed with `done`. This will result in test timeout AND uncaught rejection in case the assertion fails.

Comment: @EstusFlask: Fixed, but this still does not solve the timer-problem. Really not sure why the callback of setTimeout in `func2` is not executed. Do you have an idea what's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

`async`, raw promises and `done` callback shouldn't be used together in tests. This is a common sign that a developer isn't fully comfortable with Jest asynchronous testing, this leads to error-prone tests.

The problem with original is that `promise.then(...)` promise is ignored because it's not chained. Asynchronous test should return a promise in order for it to be chained.

`func1` and `func2` return promises that resolve immediately and produce one-tick delay rather than 1 second delay. This should be taken into account because otherwise there's a race condition with `setTimeout` being called after `advanceTimersByTime`.

It should be:

```
test('Should return success', async() => {
    const promise = index();
    await null; // match delay from await func1() 
    jest.advanceTimersByTime(2000000);
    const response = await promise;
    expect(response).toBe('success');
});
```

Comment: I am a new developer and prefer the async await sugar over promise.then(). This was exactly what I had tried initially, but got (and still get) a Timeout error. This was also the solutions to one of the many SO questions I looked at, but doesn't seem to work here. I had mentioned this in the question. I'll include it more prominently with code.

Comment: I updated the post. This is roughly the same what another answer suggests but in more organized manner. There's no need for tricks like 2000005.

Comment: Still the same :(. I didn't understand what you meant by one tick delay. Does one tick represent one line in func1?